# Photos in Twitter Archive

Tags: twitter, twitter-archive

I regularly grab an archive of my tweets from Twitter because I'm a little paranoid that I'll be kicked off the platform at some point. However, the regular archive does not include images I have uploaded to Twitter. How can I get an archive that includes the images along with the tweets?

Comment: The commentary was distracting from the overall point, I think.

Comment: Let me be a bit more curt.  That's not at all necessary nor welcome here.

Comment: It would really be much more useful to have this question answered rather than repeatedly edited.

Comment: If you can't stop editing the unnecessary name/link back into the question we'll simply delete it. If you indicate that you'll leave it alone then we can unlock it.